# How to handle big data json having more than 32767 keys

Tags: json, oracle, oracle19c

I am struggling to parse a JSON having more than 32767 keys
The format of json is shown below.
The idea is to fetch all the keys and value into a temp table , but due to length limitation unable to do so

> {"1335":"345435sd","8989SD":"jddk8","dDDSF","87868658"......}

```
declare
 j  JSON_OBJECT_T;
 i  NUMBER;
 k  JSON_KEY_LIST;
 arr JSON_ARRAY_T;
 v_key varchar2(2000);
 v_value varchar2(2000);
 CURSOR c_json IS
 select  treat(col_clob as json) myJsonCol from t_clob; -- the data is stored as clob and it need to be 
begin
  FOR rec IN c_json
  LOOP
     j := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(rec.myJsonCol);
     k := j.get_keys;
     FOR i in 1..k.COUNT
     LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line(k(i) || ' ' || j.get_String(k(i)));
        v_key :=k(i);
        v_value :=j.get_String(k(i));
       -- insert into temp(c1,c2) values(v_key,v_value);
     END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
/ 

::Oracle Error: ORA-40684: maximum number of key names exceeded::
```

Reference - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/oracle-json-restrictions.html#GUID-1DB81125-54A7-4CB6-864B-78E0E7E407C9
*PL/SQL getter method JSON_OBJECT_T.get_keys() returns at most 32767 field names for a given JSON object. An error is raised if it is applied to an object with more than 32767 fields.*

Comment: "How to handle big data json having more than 32767 keys?" The unhelpful answer is to write smaller JSON objects which have fewer keys. You could do that by grouping related keys into a child object and nesting it within the parent (effectively creating namespaces for the keys).